# Why 2*3=6 in finite field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

In a finite field $F$, say of order 7. Suppose I didn't known that it must isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_7$

By the definition of field, there exists $1 \in F$, and hence exists $1+1$ (denoted by $2$), $1+1+1$(denoted by $3$), ... ,6, and 0.

Then why $2*3$ must be $6$ in $F$, $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0 \}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_7$ as an additive group clearly, but not so clear an isomorphism as a field.

Why the operation in the field is the same as usual in general?

Comment: You can prove this (n.1)*(m.1)=((n.m).1) where n.1=1+1..1 n times if n>0 and -1+-1+...-1 -n times if n<0

Comment: here $2 \cdot 3 = (1+1+1)\cdot(1+1)=1\cdot 1+1\cdot 1+1\cdot 1+1\cdot 1+1\cdot 1+1\cdot 1=$ $= 1+1+1+1+1+1 = 6$ (use the distributive law)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$6$ denotes the element $1+1+1+1+1+1$. Now $(1+1)(1+1+1)=1+1+\cdots1 (6 times)$ by expanding the product (distributive property).